# How is the data transferred from smartphone app to ESP32 using BLE? (flutter)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I am trying to send data to an ESP32 using a smartphone app. I am using the flutter_blue package to do so. I am having issues understand the whole communication process between the 2 devices. So I am looking to better understand the way BLE communication functions.

I understand that the GATT contains a profile, which contains service(s). Each service contains a characteristic, and each characteristic has properties, a value and a descriptor.

Assuming I program the ESP32 such that whenever it receives a string signal "1", its onboard LED turns on. Where would that string be stored? in the descriptor? or the value?

What is the Profile? Service? Characteristic?
What is the role of the UUID in all of this ?

Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

[image: GATT]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHqtiCMe4NA this could help

Comment: great, thank you !